# How to nodes maintain when its storage is less then the blockchain ethereum network data.?

Tags: blockchain

I am new to Ethereum decentralized application.I am exploring how to create decentralized application. There is no single place where is data is store.So every blockchain node has all nodes data.So every day new transaction  data is store in Ethereum blockchain.So my one question is that:-

There is one node in blockchain suppose there storage configuration is 500 gb.And ethereum blockchain transactions data is greater then the node storage configuration. So in this case how to node maintain in blockchain.

And second question is that when my one node is turn off in ethereum blockchain network.In this duration many transactions happen in Ethereum blockchain network.So, how the transaction data sync in network when the node is turn off which is in Ethereum blockchain

Answer (score 1):

For nodes with a small storage I recommend you read into light clients as they provide an answer for this problem

For your second question, when you reconnect your node to the network it will sync with the blockchain and update any data that has been added to the network in the time your node was turned off

Comment: Hi kquinn,Thanks for answering this question.one question in my mind.How I read data into light client and what is your mean to light client??